# Show model parent fields in Django's admin model details

Tags: django, django-admin

I let most of my models inherit from:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        get_latest_by = 'updated_at'
```

Like this:

```
class Sale(TimeStampedModel):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    # ...
```

However, if I visit `/admin/myapp/sale/123/change/` I only see the `ip_address` field.

How can I also get to see the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields? Possibly, without having to specify every single field of `Sale` in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show this fields now, because, when you add `auto_now_add` into your model, it also set `editable=False` into your field. So, your field is read only. 
From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

To show any read only field in your admin interface, you must add `readonly_fields = ['field_name']` definition in your admin view like that:

```
@admin.register(Sale)
class SaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['created_at','updated_at']
```